# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' how to deal with this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

```
 string dt = "SELECT Last_login,SnapNo,Membership from [User] where FB_Id='" + uid1 + "'";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(dt, con);
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds1);

    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray);

    Int32 snapno = Convert.ToInt32(ds1.Tables[0].Columns["Last_login"]);
    string membership = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[2].ItemArray.ToString();
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
```

My code is as follows and i am not able to solve this problem

Please help

Comment: Why are you trying to convert an array to a `DateTime`? I'm guessing your error is happening on `DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray);`, right?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: M Babcock yes the error is coming there only..and @Andre tried that also..no success

Comment: How did you dream this code up ? What kind of magic do you expect `ItemArray` to do ?

Comment: @vini Why don't you use VS debugger?

Comment: @svick how do i extract the data in the rows kindly tell?

Comment: @vini, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to understand what is your code supposed to do and it seems you don't understand what do `Rows`, `Columns`, and `ItemArray` mean. You should probably read their documentation.

What I *think* you're trying to do is something like this:

```
var row = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0];

DateTime lastLogin = (DateTime)row["Last_login"];
Int32 snapno = (Int32)row["snapno"];
string membership = (string)row["membership"]:
```

Answer (score 2):

"*My code is as follows and i am not able to solve this problem*": Did you try to use the debugger ? In what line does the exception occur ? This question doesn't really indicate any effort to try to solve the problem your self.

Anyways, with the limited information, I will take a guess at the solution:

`ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray` is the array of all the items in the row. You can't convert that to a DateTime. It is likely you want:

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_login"];
```

By the way, [you really should use parameterized SQL queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray);
```

This doesn't really make sense, because the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) type's [ItemArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) property returns an `object[]` (which should be obvious from the name). You need to get field, for instance as string, before you can do this, like so:

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_login"]);
```

The exception you saw occurs, because all converter methods of the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class work with [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IConvertible.aspx) objects (i.e. objects whose type implements that interface). Usually only the most primitive types implement this interface, like string, int and DateTime. This is because it often makes sense to convert values of these types into one another.

If you think about it for a moment, you'll realize that there is no such common connection between an object array and the DateTime type, which is why you're getting the exception.

I would like to suggest that first you try to solve the problem on your own before coming here for help. You can learn a lot more that way, which makes you more productive on the long run.

For starters, I recommend that you read the msdn documentation about the IConvertible interface and the Convert class.

Answer (score 2):

`ItemArray` returns an array of objects. `DateTime` stores a single value. What are you expecting a conversion to do?

If the object array contains dates then you can do this

```
using system.Linq;

...

DateTime[] dates = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray.Cast<DateTime>().ToArray();
```

If you only need one date

```
DateTime dt1 = (DateTime)ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateColumn"];
```

where `"DateColumn"` is the name of your table column.

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(IConvertible);
```

`IConvertible` is an interface anything going inside that function must implement.
An array of objects returned by your SQL call does not implement ICOnvertible, and thus cannot be used as an argument.

Think of it as trying to call a function like so:

```
private void DoSomething(String input)
```

by using

```
DoSomething(999);
```